# How would i go about creating a material where i can use a color ramp to control areas or total transparency?

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine

Title pretty much says it. I want to make a material where certain areas are completely see through. For reference i want the black areas of this material to be see through like air not glass.

[image]

Comment: mmm,,, How the air looks i can't imagine that !???

Answer (score 1):

use the texture as the factor of a mix node between the surface material and a transparent node.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you need more info, please comment.

Comment: my blend mode was wrong. it works!

Comment: That's Awesome!